# Azure DevOps Pipeline - intermittently unable to load python

Tags: python, azure-devops

I created a ADO pipeline to deploy some code to a PyPi repo; however, intermittently the pipeline fails with the error

```
python3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.9.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The structure of the pipeline is a `Use Python Version` block followed by a `Command Line Script` block with the error being thrown as soon as python is called in the `Command Line Script`

Answer (score 0):

This error message generally occurs when the shared object file for Python libraries required in your Python project is not found. A common reason of this error could be the related Python version (**`Python 3.9`** in your case) is not installed on the agent machine.

1. If you are using self-hosted agent installed on yourself own Linux machine, ensure you have installed **`Python 3.9`** either by directly manual on the agent machine or using the [**Use Python version task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/use-python-version-v0?view=azure-pipelines) in pipeline.
2. If you are using [Microsoft-hosted Linux agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software) (**`ubuntu-22.04`** (**`ubuntu-latest`**) or **`ubuntu-20.04`**), the **`Python 3.9`** has been preinstalled on the agents, and the related shared object files (**`libpython3.9.so.1.0`** and **`libpython3.9.so`**) also has been downloaded into the installation directory of **`Python 3.9`**.

   - On **`ubuntu-22.04`** (**`ubuntu-latest`**) agent, the default Python version is **`Python 3.10`**. If you want to use **`Python 3.9`**, you can use the **Use Python version task** to set **`3.9`** as default version.
   - On **`ubuntu-20.04`**, the default Python version is **`Python 3.8`**.

   [image]

---

**EDIT:**

From the YAML you shared:

```yaml
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Use Python >=3.8'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '>=3.8'
```

You are using the setting "**`versionSpec: '>=3.8'`**" on the **`UsePythonVersion`** task. This setting will install the latest Python version (**`3.12`** currently) that is later than **`3.8`**. It will not install version **`3.9`**.

To install version **`3.9`**, you should use the setting "**`versionSpec: '3.9'`**".

```yaml
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Use Python 3.9'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.9'
```

---

Comment: I have a `Use Python Block` and it found a python version 

```Found tool in cache: Python 3.9.17 x64
Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: /data/tfs/vnextbuilds/cloud/dbt/agent2/_work/_tool/Python/3.9.17/x64
Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: /data/tfs/vnextbuilds/cloud/dbt/agent2/_work/_tool/Python/3.9.17/x64/bin
```

But in the next block
`python3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.9.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: What is the type of agent you are using, self-hosted or Microsoft-hosted? If self-hosted, try to login to the machine to manually reinstall **Python 3.9**. If Microsoft-hosted, which one are you using?

Comment: How would I check that?

Comment: @user1543042, Provide the YAML file of your pipeline definition.

Comment: ```pool:
  name: (MyCompany) CloudLinuxAgents
steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Use Python >=3.8'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '>=3.8'
    githubToken: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

- script: |
   python3 -m pip install --upgrade build```

Comment: @user1543042, From the YAML you shared, you are using self-hosted agent. The setting "**`versionSpec: '>=3.8'`**" on the **`UsePythonVersion`** task will install the latest Python version (`3.12` currently) that is later than `3.8`. It will not install version `3.9`.  I have updated my above answer with more details (see **EDIT**).